# Android and Eclipse - Exporting local jars through SVN

Tags: java, android, eclipse

How do I 'include' a jar inside an android project, instead of just referencing it? For example, below is a picture of my tree view for a project.

[image]

This is fine if I want to test this app on this machine, and it even works when I deploy, however if I try to check out the project through SVN, I get a message saying "The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved". Also missing lib messages such as:

*...is missing required library: C:\Users\Dane\Desktop\commons-math-2.2.jar*

etc.

I've checked the build path and checked all jars in the 'Order and Export', but it does not do what I think it does apparently.

How does one 'package' jars so they are transportable, and not left behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the jar to your project(copy the jar, click on your android project and paste)
You'll see your jar inside the project, 
then reference it once it's there.